# Using FOR XML to pass XML string as a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

I am new to XML (in SQL) and was asked to create a Stored Procedure that would pass an XML string to a field on a different server.
I am able to get the XML string using the FOR XML RAW, however I get 1 row with all records and unable to only return the individual row data.
I need to have result return 100 rows if my query has 100 rows, right now I get 1 row with all records.
How can I get the XML string to only include the row data only and not the entire string for all rows?

```
SELECT indv_hrn as 'MRN'
FROM Members_rawdata mr (nolock)
inner join Members m  (nolock)on mr.memberrecid = m.MemberRecID 
inner join Importfile i  (nolock)on m.importfileid = i.importfileid
WHERE m.importFileID = 83598 and m.Barcode is not null
FOR XML RAW ('INDEX'),ELEMENTS
```

Comment: It's better to use `FOR XML PATH() `, which offers you much more control on the creation of your XML. And please provide some sample data in a tiny sample tabel and the expected output, thx

Answer (score 2):

This answer shows an approach to get row-wise XML out of table rows:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 INT, col2 DATETIME, col3 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,GETDATE(),'test easy')
,(1,{ts'2016-01-01 23:59:00'},'test with <&> some evil ');

SELECT (SELECT col1,col2,col3 FOR XML PATH('rowData'),TYPE)
FROM @tbl
```

The result

```
<rowData><col1>1</col1><col2>2016-04-21T15:35:24.460</col2><col3>test easy</col3></rowData>
<rowData><col1>1</col1><col2>2016-01-01T23:59:00</col2><col3>test with &lt;&amp;&gt; some evil </col3></rowData>
```

Btw: You are using `NOLOCK` everywhere. If you do not know *really well!* what is going on here, you might read this and the enclosed links: [NOLOCK HINTS IN REPORT Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31980354/5089204)

Answer (score 1):

`FOR XML` generates one XML document per Result Set. Subqueries can be used to generate separate XML documents for each Row:

```
SELECT (SELECT indv_hrn AS MRN FOR XML PATH ('INDEX'), TYPE) AS [XML]
FROM Members_rawdata mr (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Members    m (NOLOCK) ON mr.memberrecid = m.MemberRecID 
INNER JOIN Importfile i (NOLOCK) ON m.importfileid = i.importfileid
WHERE m.importFileID = 83598 AND m.Barcode IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This answer is - uhm - 10 years late :-)  There's absolutely no need to generate XML through string concatenation. T-SQL offers really great support to build an XML clean and easy, with namespaces, implicit encodings of forbidden characters, date-format and all this stuff...

Comment: I've read your answer to the end and this makes it even worse... You show that you know how to do it and still you suggest the wrong and dangerous approach. Your code might work. It will be implemented in some productive  environment. And a while later there is the first `indv_hrn` with a forbidden character. You do not even know what datatype this column is...

Comment: @Shnugo OK. Point taken.

Comment: As your answer is correct now I'll change my vote :-)